# akka-http and JWT

Tags: jwt, akka-http

I'm using akka-http-session with the bootzooka seed project.  I'm curious what the recommended approach is to implement JWT authentication in akka-http.  It appears akka-http-session supports it however the documentation seems to be lacking and examples shown are all using cookie based authentication.

Thank you in advance,
CN

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful implementing akka-http-sessions:

https://github.com/softwaremill/akka-http-session